# Removing the MeMenu

Tags: indicator, menu

I want to remove the MeMenu, without removing the logout/shutdown/restart/etc. button next to it. I never use social networks, so I have no use for this function. Any tips?

Comment: You can remove it from panel without completely removing it from the system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`sudo apt-get remove indicator-me`

If you also want to get rid of the Messaging Applet:

`sudo apt-get remove indicator-me indicator-messages`

Comment: There's no need to remove indicator-messages for this purpose. That will remove the messaging indicator as well.

Comment: Oh, I don't want that! Anything else?

Comment: Wait, that worked! It completely removed it! Perfect.
I just removed that last part about indicator-messages.

Answer (score 9):

To only display the session manager, launch `gconf-editor` from the terminal or the "Run Application" dialog (call by pressing `Alt+F2`). Next browse to `/system/indicator/me/` and change the vaulue for `display` from `1` to `0`.

[image: gconf]

Or you can just run this command in the terminal:

`gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 0`

To re-enable the MeMeun, run:

`gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 1`

Comment: Oh, wait, just one thing. Not really important, but the icon is still there. The username is gone though, which is the most important.

Comment: As @Lyristor said this doesn't quite do as requested!

Comment: Hmmm.... Are you on Lucid? It works for me on Maverick. Watch: http://people.ubuntu.com/~andrewsomething/misc/memenu.ogv

Comment: Reboot. You'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add applications you don't want to appear in the dropdown to the blacklist at `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist` by copying their configuration from `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications` into that directory. See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin-libnotify/+bug/480030) for more discussion.